# Why is the text in these column cells not centered?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the following example LaTeX table code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c|ccccccc@{}}
    \hline
                        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Testword and large Text1} & \hphantom{------} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Testword and large Text2} \\ \hline
                        & 111 & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
    Test-Row-1  & 74,15 & 49,74 & 60,40 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,83 \\
    Test-Row-2   & 23,16 & 11,35 & 25,70 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
    Test-Row-3  & 33,90 & 10,28 & 23,78 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
    \\\hline
                        & 111 & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
    Test-Row-5 & 69,54 & 58,08 & 59,14 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 1,49 \\
    Test-Row-6  & 35,49 & 23,25 & 27,95 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
    Test-Row-7 & 27,77 & 24,54 & 23,29 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

For one thing, unfortunately, nothing is centered in the table. The problem is, the larger the words in the row containing `111 & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444 & 5555 & 666666`, the more likely the table is centered. But so with the words as I need them I have unfortunately not yet managed it even with \phantom{}.

Furthermore I find the table hard to read and I'm still looking for a way to make the free row `(between Test-Row-3 and Test-Row-4)` more beautiful. The row above `Test-Row-4` should be clearly separated from the upper one, but it is still a requirement that all information is in one table.

Here is a picture of how the table looks at the moment:
[image]

Comment: You never should use `\sizebox` with tables – it leads to inconsistent font sizes.

Comment: if you use a `\multicolumn` span that is wider than the coumns that it spans then all the extra width goes into the last column spanned. so use narrowe headings or make the columns wider (for example increase  `\tabcolsep` and please, remove `\resizebox{0.9\textwidth}{!}{%` I

Comment: @Berdard Is there a way to keep the font size the same in tables, so that the font size is not different in each table?

Comment: Not using \resizebox, or redesigning the table layout. The `makecell` package can also be useful, as it allows for line breaks in standard columns.

Comment: @campa I had seen that you had made a suggestion as to how I could make the table look reasonably pretty. However, the answer is no longer available.

Comment: I removed it because the centering was still somewhat off; I have to think about it.

Comment: @campa oh well, thanks for the help. Should I get further I would get back to you. Perhaps the layout of the table can be changed so that the centering problem no longer occurs

Answer (score 4):

I offer three flavors of the many available. The first using the packages `multirow` and `makecell` to split the long headings using `\\` inside the cell.

The second using only the package `nicematrix` that provides the powerfull command `\Block`  allowing a more compact code. The package also allows for general directives to stretch all cell vertically.

Finally, with a fine control of the width of the columns, making them all with the same width, regardless of their content.

The separation between rows can be increased using adding vertical space after the `\\` as `[7pt]`.

[image: ab]

[image: c]

*Note on using line break within cells:* It is very good to have this ability available. It is not necessary in this simple MWE, but in the real world, if your long heading grows, it will enlarge the table and destroy the layout. Try it yourself.

[image: bad]

Next stage in beautification is taking care of the rules and headings (not part of the question).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}    
    
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c|ccccccc@{}}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirowcell{2}{Testword and \\ large Text1}}  &
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirowcell{2}{Testword and \\ large Text2}} \\
                    &       &       &       &  &      &     &        \\ 
        \hline
                    & 111   & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444  & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-1  & 74,15 & 49,74 & 60,40 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,83   \\
        Test-Row-2  & 23,16 & 11,35 & 25,70 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-3  & 33,90 & 10,28 & 23,78 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\[6pt]%increase vertical separation
        \hline
                    & 111   & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444  & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-5  & 69,54 & 58,08 & 59,14 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 1,49   \\
        Test-Row-6  & 35,49 & 23,25 & 27,95 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-7  & 27,77 & 24,54 & 23,29 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\caption{Intra-Klassen-Abweichung with multirow and makecell}
\label{tab:intra-class-deviation}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
    \begin{NiceTabular}{@{}c|c c c c c c c@{}}[
        cell-space-top-limit = 5pt, % stretch the cells
        cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt]
        \hline
        &\Block{1-3}{Testword and \\ large Text1}   &   &   &   
        &\Block{1-3}{Testword and \\ large Text2}   &   &\\
        \hline
                    & 111   & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-1  & 74,15 & 49,74 & 60,40 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 0,83   \\
        Test-Row-2  & 23,16 & 11,35 & 25,70 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-3  & 33,90 & 10,28 & 23,78 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 0,00   \\[7pt] %increase vertical separation
        \hline
                    & 111 & 22222   & 33333 &  & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-5  & 69,54 & 58,08 & 59,14 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 1,49   \\
        Test-Row-6  & 35,49 & 23,25 & 27,95 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-7  & 27,77 & 24,54 & 23,29 &  & 0,00& 0,00 & 0,00   \\ \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}%
\caption{Intra-Klassen-Abweichung with nicematrix}
\label{tab:intra-class-deviation2}
\end{table} 

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth}}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c| *{3}{P{0.1}} P{0} *{3}{P{0.1}} @{}}
        \hline
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirowcell{2}{Testword and \\ large Text1}}  &
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirowcell{2}{Testword and \\ large Text2}} \\
        &           &       &       &  &      &     &        \\ 
        \hline
                    & 111   & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444  & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-1  & 74,15 & 49,74 & 60,40 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,83   \\
        Test-Row-2  & 23,16 & 11,35 & 25,70 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-3  & 33,90 & 10,28 & 23,78 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\[6pt]%increse vertical space
        \hline
                    & 111   & 22222 & 33333 &  & 444  & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
        Test-Row-5  & 69,54 & 58,08 & 59,14 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 1,49   \\
        Test-Row-6  & 35,49 & 23,25 & 27,95 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\
        Test-Row-7  & 27,77 & 24,54 & 23,29 &  & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    \caption{Intra-Klassen-Abweichung with multirow and makecell.\\
         All columns with the same width.}
    \label{tab:intra-class-deviation3}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this, with the `w` column type, and  some fancy rules?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[47]
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering\arrayrulecolor{LightGray!60!Lavender}
    \arrayrulewidth=1.2pt
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c!{\color{LightGray!60!Lavender}\vrule width 2.4pt}*{3}{wc{1.25cm} }!{\color{LightGray!60!Lavender}\vrule width 6pt} *{3}{wc{1.25cm} }@{}}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Testword and large Text1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Testword and large Text2} \\ \hline
    & 111 & 22222 & 33333 & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
    Test-Row-1 & 74,15 & 49,74 & 60,40 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,83 \\
    Test-Row-2 & 23,16 & 11,35 & 25,70 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
    Test-Row-3 & 33,90 & 10,28 & 23,78 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
     & & &
    \\\hline
    & 111 & 22222 & 33333 & 444 & 5555 & 666666 \\ \hline
    Test-Row-5 & 69,54 & 58,08 & 59,14 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 1,49 \\
    Test-Row-6 & 35,49 & 23,25 & 27,95 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\
    Test-Row-7 & 27,77 & 24,54 & 23,29 & 0,00 & 0,00 & 0,00 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The width of your multicolumn cells is wider than sum of spanned columns. As mentioned in comments below your question, you need to increase widths of spanned columns, for example to prescribe their widths as is done in the MWE below.

With use the `S` columns type defined in the `siunitx` package, prescribed columns width with `table-column-width=3.3em` (estimated 1/3 of multicolumn width) and employed rules defined in the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}    % used document class is unknown
\usepackage{geometry}   % page layout is unknown

\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
    {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}c *{3}{S[table-format=2.2,
                            table-column-width=3.3em]}
                     *{3}{S[table-format=1.2,
                            table-column-width=3.3em]} @{}}
    \toprule
    & \mcc[3]{Test word and large Text1}    & \mcc[3]{Test word and large Text2} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}
    \cmidrule(l){5-7}
            & {111} & {22222}   & {33333}   & {444} & {5555}    & {666666}  \\ 
    \midrule
Test-Row-1  & 74,15 & 49,74     & 60,40     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 0,83      \\
Test-Row-2  & 23,16 & 11,35     & 25,70     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 0,00      \\
Test-Row-3  & 33,90 & 10,28     & 23,78     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 0,00      \\
    \midrule
            & {111} & {22222}   & {33333}   & {444} & {5555}    & {666666}  \\
    \midrule
Test-Row-5  & 69,54 & 58,08     & 59,14     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 1,49      \\
Test-Row-6  & 35,49 & 23,25     & 27,95     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 0,00      \\
Test-Row-7  & 27,77 & 24,54     & 23,29     & 0,00  & 0,00      & 0,00      \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But also in your solution the 5555 is centered, but the cells below (0,00) are not centered

Comment: @john-mueller, yes of you so quibbling
 :-). error is les than half digit width. Corrected now.